# Android studio error: "can't generate a git version, this is not a git project"

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I can not compile the project, this error occurs: [**can't generate a git version, this is not a git project**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5IYp.png). When I compile the project on another computer (Hackintosh) everything works without a single error. "git init" and other commands have no effect.
P.S. I have the latest version of macOS and Android Studio.

Comment: This seems to need the [tag:android-studio] tag, and/or one of the more specific ones for the particular version of android studio. The generic "android" tag probably should never be used as it's too generic. I think the [tag:git] tag doesn't really apply either as this does not seem to have anything to do with Git itself, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: @torek, yeah, I think you're right. Thanks for the advice!